# Submitting Update Request with File Using Inertia Form Helper

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I was editing employee data on inertia vue3 application with Laravel on the backend and I was trying to send an update request with image. I read from the inertia documentation that it is not possible to directly use the put method with file "for some languages", and it recommends to use "method spoofing, which allows you to upload the files using post". It also shows example, but without form helper.

I tried it as per the recommendation and it works, but I don't want to loose the benefits of form helper like getting errors. Is there any way to do it with the form helper?

```
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia'
const form = reactive({
    employee_type_id: props.employee.employee_type_id,
    first_name: props.employee.first_name,
    middle_name: props.employee.middle_name,
    last_name: props.employee.last_name,
    email: props.employee.user.email,
    badge_number: props.employee.badge_number,
    image: '',
})
function submit(id) {
    Inertia.post(route('employee.update', id), {
        _method: 'put',
        employee_type_id: form.employee_type_id,
        first_name: form.first_name,
        middle_name: form.middle_name,
        last_name: form.last_name,
        email: form.email,
        badge_number: form.badge_number,
        image: form.image,
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the _method: 'put' in your useForm with your data.

Comment: Please show how this suggestion can be put to use by sharing some example code.

Comment: @foobar the  _method: 'put', is allready in

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Solve It Easily**

```
import { router,useForm } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
const props = defineProps(["employee"]);
   
     const form = useForm({
        employee_type_id: props.employee.employee_type_id,
        first_name: props.employee.first_name,
        middle_name: props.employee.middle_name,
        last_name: props.employee.last_name,
        email: props.employee.user.email,
        badge_number: props.employee.badge_number,
        image: '',
    });
    
    const submit = () => {
        router.post(route("employee.update", props.employee?.id), {
            preserveScroll: true,
            _method: "put",
            employee_type_id: form.employee_type_id,
            first_name: form.first_name,
            middle_name: form.middle_name,
            last_name: form.last_name,
            email: form.email,
            badge_number: form.badge_number,
            image: form.image,
        });
    };
```